# Control a edittext from other XML file

Tags: android

I have a textbox in one XML layout file.Currently I'm using the R.layout.main (other xml file) that contains a button. When this button gets pressed I need the text to be changed in the required textbox. How can I pass control from one xml to another xml?

Comment: do you mean button and edittext are in different layout or in different views?

Comment: Yes...they both are in different views.

Comment: you can directly update using findbyviewid() in the onbuttonclicklistner(). didn't you tried that?

Comment: When I've tried that I keep on getting a Force Close error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you trying to do broh?

[image]

[image]

You can do this by this :

```
  1) public class TxtActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View b1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    String akey = ed.getText().toString();
                    Intent i = new Intent(TxtActivity.this, cl1.class);
                     b.putString("akey", akey);
                     i.putExtras(b);
                     startActivity(i);
                     finish();
        }
    });}}




  2) public class cl1 extends Activity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a);
    EditText nw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s = b.getString("akey");
    nw.setText(s);


}

 }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply bro. Your post indeed helped me.